# apriori algorithm hangs my system when I use it in R studio

Tags: r

Am trying to execute the apriori algorithm. If I use examples shared in blogs and in help content it works fine and gives results. But when I implement it by using the `data.frame` which has data where I have to implement then it shows warning after that it hangs system.

I tried reducing the number of rows and columns to 5 and then it worked fine.

But same thing when I implement with 25 rows and columns it hangs.

Here is the sample code:
For 5 rows and columns

```
#select 5 columns
apriori_mat_spec<-Apriori_material[,c(1:5)]    
#select 5 rows    
apriori_mat_spec<-apriori_mat_spec[1:5,]    
trans3<-as(apriori_mat_spec,"transactions")    
inspect(trans3)    
result <- apriori(trans3, parameter = list(support = 0.3))    
inspect(result)
```

For 25 rows and 25 columns

```
apriori_mat_spec<-Apriori_material[,c(1:25)]    
apriori_mat_spec<-apriori_mat_spec[1:25,]    
trans3<-as(apriori_mat_spec,"transactions")    
inspect(trans3)    
result <- apriori(trans3, parameter = list(support = 0.3))    
inspect(result)
```

System is getting hanged when i use 25 rows and columns to a dataframe with a warning:

> Error: cannot allocate vector of size 256.0 Mb
>       In addition: Warning messages:
>       1: In unique.default(lengths(x)) :
>         Reached total allocation of 8084Mb: see help(memory.size)
>       2: In unique.default(lengths(x)) :
>         Reached total allocation of 8084Mb: see help(memory.size)
>       3: In unique.default(lengths(x)) :
>         Reached total allocation of 8084Mb: see help(memory.size)
>       4: In unique.default(lengths(x)) :
>         Reached total allocation of 8084Mb: see help(memory.size)

I have increased memory size to 99999 by using

```
memory.limit(size=99999)
```

still problem persists, when i use `data.frame` with 25 rows and columns.

sample data here

```
Material 1  Material 2  Material 3  Material 4  Material 5
1204315     1204324     6041541     7508226     7509677
7511601             
6961200     7514100     7522029     
7512374     7516799         
419110      6000832     6960800     7010000     7508229
```

output of summary for the above data
[image: final output for 5 rows and 5 columns]

Comment: do you have '99999' M or > 8G RAM on your machine?

Comment: Yes, I have 8GB RAM Patric in my system

Comment: Without your data we can't duplicate this. Can you supply the data or can you create a data set that also fails this way? Does any 25x25 data frame fail? Or at least show the output of `summary` on your objects.

Comment: Where does the `apriori` function come from? Which package? You should say.

Comment: I mean more than 8G, because you already `Reached total allocation of 8084Mb`. If only 8G on your system, I think it doesn't work.  which package are you used? I'd like to take a try.

Comment: Do you get a helpful warning message like this at the start of the run: `You chose a very low absolute support count of 1. You might run out of memory! Increase minimum support.`. Have you tried its suggestion?

Comment: @Spacedman please check the edited question with sample data. apriori algorithm is with the package named arules